# A friend asked me to store his possessions for a week, but he hasn't collected it in 3 months. Can I get rid of it?

Tags: england-and-wales

I'm in England. A so-called friend of mine left a lot of his possessions (clothes, books, homeware, keyboards, printers) at my place, saying he'd collect it with a week. It's now been three months, and he's no closer to taking it back.

Is it legal for me to donate it to charity? I've asked him time and time again (on Whatsapp/text) and he always replies with "OK I'll look into it" but never does anything.

So I would like to know if I can get rid of it without worrying about him suing me.

Comment: related: http://www.xkcd.com/1150/

Comment: Slightly more related: Goods (Interference with Goods) Act 1977... http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/32

Answer (score 3):

Inform him of what you intend to do and by what by what date.   Make sure that you can document that you did give him notice -- so not sure sure if Whatsapp/text would do -- I would use a registered letter, and a letter which is also sent in CC to your solicitor.

He can always sue you, but he does not stand to win if you can show that you have given him fair warning.